# RegEx for finding a specific pattern in a multi-line input

Tags: regex

I have a file like this. All I want to match is, the whole module of `asdf`.

```
module asdf (a,b);

input a;

output b;

assign b = a;

endmodule


module abc (a,b);

input a;

output b;

assign b = a + b ;

endmodule

module xyz (a,b);

input a;

output b;

assign b = a - c;

endmodule
```

It means, I want to match only below content. I tried multiple ways like

```
module asdf (a,b);

input a;

output b;

assign b = a;

endmodule
```

When I tried

```
(module asdf .*(\n)+(.*\n)+)+endmodule
```

It is matching till the last occurrence of endmodule in the file. But, I want the first occurrence of endmodule.

```
(module asdf .*(\n)+(.*\n)+)+endmodule
```

Comment: First, indent your code otherwise hard to help. Spend some time [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this regex,

```
\bmodule\s+asdf\b[\w\W]+?\bendmodule\b
```

Start matching with `module` as whole word (`\b` are called **[word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)** and helps in matching word and not partially) followed by one or more whitespace then `asdf` as whole word and then `[\w\W]*?` matches any character one or more times in non-greedy way followed by `endmodule` as whole word.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SiykYp/1)**